# How to use Racket in terminal?

Tags: racket

I'm having no luck finding a way to have this work the way I'd like it to, so if anyone could help that would be so greatly appreciated.

What I'd like is to be able to do this on Terminal:

`> racket`

And then be able to enter Racket commands and have them compile. Like,

```
> (+ 1 2)
> 3
```

And hopefully some commands like

```
> racket myprog.rkt
> 3
```

Where `myprog.rkt` was just the file containing `(+ 1 2)`.

I'm new to this so sorry if it's an obvious question but I just don't know how to make it work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You're describing almost exactly what the `racket` executable is doing.  The only difference is that your `myprog.rkt` would need to have a `#lang racket` at the top.

If you're using a Mac, you'll need to run the executable with a direct path, or add it to your environment's `$PATH`, or make a symlink to it.  You will find the executable in the `bin` subdirectory.

If you're on Windows, you have to do the same -- either add the Racket directory to the `PATH` in the system settings, or run it directly.  On windows, you should have a startup link to the Racket executable which will run in a cmd box.  (And note that if you look at the Racket directory, there will not be a `bin` subdirectory.)

Comment: @snario See also the documentation on xrepl: http://docs.racket-lang.org/xrepl/index.html?q=xrepl

Comment: Right! What I want is to be able to, anywhere is terminal, just say `racket` and have that executable run, just like how python works. How do I add it to my path?

Comment: sounds like you have a question about how to add something to your path. What operating system are you using?

Comment: Create an alias in `~/.bash_profile`: `alias racket='/Applications/Racket\ v6.1.1.1/bin/racket'`

Comment: Don't do an alias -- that would work only in bash, not in other shells, and not from scripts.

Answer (score 0):

It would a great idea to first download Racket, you can find the download file or also do it with Snap or Flathub, check it [out](https://racket-lang.org/download/). To complement @EliBarzilay, if you are on GNU/Linux, on a debian based system you need to install racket, running:

```
sudo apt install racket
```

Or in RHEL/Fedora:

```
sudo dnf install racket
```

for then:

```
racket myprog.rkt
```